# Generate brace expansion from list of files

Tags: bash, readline, brace-expansion

This brace expression will generate a list of files:

```
$ touch {foo{.t,t.t},other.txt,test{,.{ascii,t{est.qt,x{t,xt}}}}} 

$ ls
foo.t foot.t other.txt test test.ascii test.test.qt test.txt test.txxt
```

Is it possible to convert back a list of files to a brace expansion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the list of files given above you just need to press ( M-{ ) in an empty command line:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>{</kbd>

to get:

```
$ {foo{.t,t.t},other.txt,test{,.{ascii,t{est.qt,x{t,xt}}}}}
```

Or, write `fo` and press the same keys to get:

```
$ foo{.t,t.t}
```

That is, complete into braces all files that match the string `fo` (before point).

From `man bash`

> complete-into-braces (M-{)
>   Perform filename completion and insert the list of possible completions enclosed within braces so the list is available to the shell.